# Minimizing SubModular Function: Cardinality

Tags: ds.algorithms, approximation-algorithms, submodularity

Given a submodular function f: 2^V to reals (not necessarily monotone), and an integer k, find a set S such that |S| <= k and  such that f(S) is minimized.

When the size constraint is |S| >=k, the problem is NP-hard.  What is known about when the constraint is |S| <= k?

Comment: The complement of a submodular function is submodular, so there exists a direct reduction from the hard $|S| \geq k$ case to your $|S| \leq |V| - k$ problem.

Answer (score 2):

It is NP-hard. [Svitkina and Fleischer showed](https://arxiv.org/abs/0805.1071) that there is no $o(\sqrt{n/\log n})$ approximation using only a polynomial number of queries.